# Linear mixed model with heterogeneous variance

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to fit a mixed model that can account for heterogeneous variance using lmer() function in lme4 package.

Right now, my model structure in lme4 looks like this:

```r
lmer(log_biomass ~ Group + Time + 
    Group*Time + (1|Field:Group) + 
    (1|Field:Group:Time),  
    data = uav_data_soy,REML = FALSE)
```

The package nlme provides the functionality of explicitly defining a factor with heterogeneous variance using the weight argument in lme() function. Is there a way to do a similar process in lme4 package?

Furthermore, if I have to define the random effects i.e.(1|Field:Group) + (1|Field:Group:Time) in the above lme4 model in nlme framework, how can I define that? I could not figure out a way to write such a random effect structure in nlme. Any help in these issues is much appreciated.

Comment: Please can you explain your study design, and your research question(s). How did you arrive at this random structure ?

Comment: I have data samples from 13 fields (repeated 3 times) and it is related to cereal rye dry biomass. The fields are categorized into four distinct groups according to different management practices. The goal here is to model cereal rye biomass as a function of both fixed and random effects. We are trying to look how cereal rye growth vary across  different fields and time.  Our main focus how much of the behaviour of the data can be explained by grouping factors over the time course considered after accounting for random sources of variability in the data?

Comment: Each field have multiple samples that are repeatedly measured for three times and these fields can be grouped together in 4 groups. This is the reason we have random effect of Field (Group) and random effect of Field (Group)*Time.